# error: The return type 'CategoryState' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter

I tried to put the route to Another Class on the Same Page and wrote this code as mentioned in the flutter Doc, but I get this:

> error: The return type `CategoryState` isn't a `Widget`, as required
> by the closure's context.

Page code:

[image: Page code]

Navigation code:

[image: Navigation code]

Comment: Code is preferred to images as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics): the builder function of the `MaterialPageRoute` class should return a widget. Both `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget` extend the `Widget` class and thus can be used here.

But in your case the `CategoryState` class does not extend any of them, and it's the reason you are having that error.

You need to use the `Category` class instead.

It should then look like:

**PAGE :**

```dart
class Category extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategoryState createState() => _CategoryState();
}

class _CategoryState extends State<Category> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Column(
          children: [
              Container(child: Text("Music")),
              Container(child: Text("Projects")),
              Container(child: Text("Essay")),
          ],
      );
  }
}
```

**NAVIGATION**

```dart
Navigator.push(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Category())
);
```

Furthermore, I would advise you to add a suffix to this class name (e.g. CategoryScreen) in order to avoid name conflicts in case you have another class (e.g. a model) with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

class CategoryState is not a widget it's just a Dart class you want to navigate to Category()